# How do I verify that there is only a specific text in a element and it's descendants?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I want to verify that there is only a specific text "Only Text" in a element and it's descendants. Here is an Example code:

```
 <div id ="selected-item">
      <div class="descendant">
      </div>
        <div class="descendant">
          <img class="logo-image" src="image.svg">
        </div>
      <div class="name">Only text
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Code trials? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to test the first element and its descendants. With XPath 1.0 :

```
count(//div[@id="selected-item"]//div[@class="name" and contains(text(),"Only text")])=1
```

Output : `true`